# No devices found with name or id 'emulator-5554'

Tags: android, flutter

I have been trying to run my emulator, but it consistently says no devices found!! It shows like this.

[image]

It won't run, when I run the flutter project.

Comment: Did you try with restarting the ide?

Comment: try on terminal `flutter run`

Comment: tried both. i even uninstalled the ide and reinstall it. "it says : G:\MAD\flutter_app>flutter run
No supported devices connected.
The following devices were found, but are not supported by this project:
Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 97.0.1072.69
If you would like your app to run on web, consider running `flutter create .` to generate projects for these platforms."

Comment: Have you tried using `flutter doctor -v` in the command line? Should reveal any faults with installation or setup.

Answer (score 1):

Run `flutter run --verbose` in the terminal to get much richer blogs to see what's te issue.

If everything else fails you can try installing [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com) which is best emulator for running flutter apps anyway in my opinion

Comment: thank you i try installing Genymotion.